# calling another method from different class

Tags: java, oop

I was practicing java. And I created a method in another class within the same package such that,

```
class ArraysPractice2{
    
    int n;
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    
    double averageA(int [] arr)
    {
        double ans = 0;
        int added = 0;
        int total = arr.length;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            added = added + arr[i];
            
        }
        
        ans = added / total;
        
        return ans;
    }
    
}
```

and then I have a main method has following code,

```
    ArraysPractice2 aT = new ArraysPractice2();
    
    int[] testArr = new int[10];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++)
    {
        testArr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    
    aT.averageA(testArr);
```

I expected that `aT.averageA` would give me the average of `testArr` array.
However, it does not give me anything.

What are the issues in here?

I have a feeling that I am not understanding OOP well..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might _give_ you that value, but you're not doing anything with it (printing it, for instance).

Comment: ah, I thought the return sould give me the value of the answer. So, if I want to show the answer, I must put the system.out.println not return! Great, thank you for your help.

Comment: It's actually quite common to confuse returning with printing at the very earliest stages of computer science. I've seen it happen to quite a lot of people, and I presume that's what's happening to you. Returning essentially just allows the function call to be evaluated as an expression, with its evaluation being the returned value. It does not print it to the console or do anything else with it. For instance, `double avg = aT.averageA(testArr);` would (hopefully) get the average and store it in a `double` called `avg`.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what happened. Ah, so it is storing a value instead of printing it.

Comment: In your main(), you should do System.out.println("average = " + aT.averageA(testArr));

Answer (score 0):

```
 aT.averageA(testArr);
```

You are not receiving/using a value you have got in the line above.

Try this:

```
double res = aT.averageA(testArr);
System.out.println("aT.averageA(testArr = "+res);
```

and you should see your value.